# Can't start cq5 service under windows 7 64bit

Tags: service, windows-7, 64-bit, aem

One year ago I installed successfully CQ5 as a windows service under Windows 7 32bit. After that I've switched to Windows 7 **64bit**. Currently I have a project using CQ5 so I install again it (under Window 64bit). CQ5 starts fine with `crx-quickstart/bin/start.bat` using command line. Also I don't see any problem when installing as service with the command `instsrv.bat cq5`:

```
Installing service cq5
    runs in   E:\servers\cq5-server\author\crx-quickstart
    uses      E:\servers\cq5-server\author\crx-quickstart\opt\helpers\\..\..\app\cq-quickstart-5.5.0-standalone.jar
    starts    org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main
    redirects output to: E:\servers\cq5-server\author\crx-quickstart\logs\startup.log
```

But when I run `net start cq5`, I get an error as below:

```
The cq5 service is starting.
The cq5 service could not be started.

A service specific error occurred: 0.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3547.
```

And checking log file commons-daemon.2013-09-01.log, I see:

```
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.8.0 64-bit) started
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [info]  Running 'cq5' Service...
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [info]  Starting service...
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [error] Failed creating java 
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [error] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [error] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [info]  Run service finished.
[2013-09-01 23:26:36] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Could anyone let me know what I'm wrong?
I'm following the instructions at [Installing and Starting Adobe Experience Manager as a Windows Service](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html)

Comment: I guess the location of your JDK has changed.  Have you updated the JAVA_HOME environment variable or location specified in start-service.bat to reflect this?  The service needs to be reinstalled if the JDK location changes.

Comment: thank for your comment but the variable is setting correctly and i can run 'java' without an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set up JDK by copying java folder from another computer and setting the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`. So maybe something is missing in registry.

Below is how to fix the problem:

1. First follow correctly the first 3 steps in the instructions at [Installing and Starting Adobe Experience Manager as a Windows Service](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html#Installing%20and%20Starting%20AEM%20as%20a%20Windows%20Service). (In my case, I used `prunsrv_amd64` to replace `prunsrv`)
2. Edit again the bat file `instsrv.bat` by changing

   ```
   :: path to a jvm.dll or "auto"
   set jvm_path="auto"
   ```

   to

   ```
   :: path to a jvm.dll or "auto"
   set jvm_path="%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
   ```
3. Finally run `instsrv.bat CQ5` under `\crx-quickstart\opt\helpers`

P/S: This way also does help in case of Windows XP 32bit (I've tested)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the instsrv script to use the 64 bit prunsrv.exe. You'll just want to open up the script and change all prunsrv commands to prunsrv_amd64 or prunsrv_ia64.

Comment: Thank for your answer! However this step is in the instruction that I followed but did not help fix.